# Will AngularJS and Wordpress SEO techniques conflict with each other?

Tags: seo, wordpress, meta-tags, yoast, angular

I am very new to WordPress. I implemented a web site using AngularJS and these SEO techniques:

- Title tag
- Meta description tags
- Heading tags
- 'alt' tags
- 'og' tags

I am planning to use WordPress as a CMS for my site. Is it okay to use WordPress SEO techniques (and plugins) in addition to the techniques I've already used in AngularJS?

Comment: I am not following. If you are able to do what you want, what does it matter what you have used. Or are you asking what to do for SEO?

Comment: @RohitGupta I already used SEO in angular. My question, is that fine if I use  SEO methods in wordpress level also?

Comment: Search engines don't use `og` tags at all.  That is social media optimization.

Comment: Are there going to be some pages on your site handled with WordPress and some with Angular, or are you trying embed one technology within the pages of the other?